# Multiple instances of AM PM picker

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I have a HTML in which i have to use start time and end time. for doing this i am using the AM PM picker of jquery.But only one instance of this AM PM picker is working .i cant able to use multiple instances of this AM PM picker........How can i able to do that....

The whole source code is present in A Zip folder....

http://www.4shared.com/file/ZQy2A3DU/DateTime.html

alternativery you can have a look on the code thru 
http://jsfiddle.net/premseoul/BjDYP/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this
http://keith-wood.name/timeEntry.html